# Json Parsing in swift 4.2 using Codable

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, codable, decodable

I am working on one project.I got one response from API.Now I want to fetch that response through **JsonDecode().decod** funcion with structure using decodable class.

I have made codable structure but it gives me error like :

**The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format.**

**My API Response is:**

```
{
    auth = 1;
    data =     {
        "dealer_rating" =         {
            average = "3.5";
            "average_width" = "70%";
            count = 2;
            dislikes = 0;
            likes = 2;
            rate1 = 4;
            "rate1_label" = "Atenci\U00f3n al cliente";
            "rate1_width" = "80%";
            rate2 = "3.5";
            "rate2_label" = "Proceso de compra";
            "rate2_width" = "70%";
            rate3 = 3;
            "rate3_label" = "Experiencia general";
            "rate3_width" = "60%";
        };
        review =         (
                        {
                average = 3;
                "post_author" = 16;
                "post_content" = "Test of iOS developer.";
                "post_title" = "iOS Test";
                rate1 = 3;
                "rate1_label" = "Atenci\U00f3n al cliente";
                rate2 = 3;
                "rate2_label" = "Proceso de compra";
                rate3 = 3;
                "rate3_label" = "Experiencia general";
                "stm_recommended" = yes;
                username = "";
            },
                        {
                average = 4;
                "post_author" = 22;
                "post_content" = vvvvvvvvvv;
                "post_title" = vvvvvvvvvv;
                rate1 = 5;
                "rate1_label" = "Atenci\U00f3n al cliente";
                rate2 = 4;
                "rate2_label" = "Proceso de compra";
                rate3 = 3;
                "rate3_label" = "Experiencia general";
                "stm_recommended" = yes;
                username = Vnn;
            }
        );
    };
    message = "Review found.";
    status = 1;
}
```

**My Decodable Structure is :**

```
struct resDelerReview : Codable {
    struct struDataString : Codable {
        var average:String?
        var rate1:Int
        var rate1_label:String?
        var rate2:Int
        var rate2_label:String?
        var rate3:Int
        var rate3_label:String?
        var likes:Int
        var dislikes:Int
        var count:Int
        var rate1_width:String?
        var rate2_width:String?
        var rate3_width:String?
        var average_width:String?
    }

    struct struReviewList : Codable {
        var post_author:String?
        var username:String?
        var post_content:String?
        var post_title:String?
        var rate1:String?
        var rate1_label:String?
        var rate2:String?
        var rate2_label:String?
        var rate3:String?
        var rate3_label:String?
        var stm_recommended:String?
        var average:Int
    }


    struct reviewRating : Codable {
        let dealer_rating:struDataString
        let review:[struReviewList]
    }

    let data:reviewRating
    let status:Bool
    let auth:Bool
    let message:String?
}
```

**Postman response in text**

```
{
    "data": {
        "dealer_rating": {
            "average": "3.5",
            "rate1": 4,
            "rate1_label": "Atención al cliente",
            "rate2": 3.5,
            "rate2_label": "Proceso de compra",
            "rate3": 3,
            "rate3_label": "Experiencia general",
            "likes": 2,
            "dislikes": 0,
            "count": 2,
            "rate1_width": "80%",
            "rate2_width": "70%",
            "rate3_width": "60%",
            "average_width": "70%"
        },
        "review": [
            {
                "post_author": "16",
                "username": "",
                "post_content": "Test of iOS developer.",
                "post_title": "iOS Test",
                "rate1": "3",
                "rate1_label": "Atención al cliente",
                "rate2": "3",
                "rate2_label": "Proceso de compra",
                "rate3": "3",
                "rate3_label": "Experiencia general",
                "stm_recommended": "yes",
                "average": 3
            },
            {
                "post_author": "22",
                "username": "Vnn",
                "post_content": "vvvvvvvvvv",
                "post_title": "vvvvvvvvvv",
                "rate1": "5",
                "rate1_label": "Atención al cliente",
                "rate2": "4",
                "rate2_label": "Proceso de compra",
                "rate3": "3",
                "rate3_label": "Experiencia general",
                "stm_recommended": "yes",
                "average": 4
            }
        ]
    },
    "status": true,
    "auth": true,
    "message": "Review found."
}
```

**My Postman Response is:**

[image]

Please help me guys I am getting stuck.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you post your Postman response as text?

Comment: ok just a minute

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is quite clear if you read the whole of it, it is the property `rate2` that is declared as an `Int` but contains 3.5 for one of the elements

So change it in the `struDataString` struct to

```
var rate2: Double
```

**Note** There are several other similar fields like rate2 in the `struDataString` and those are very likely that they may contain double values to like the other `rateX` fields. You might want to check out the documentation for all of them

Comment: ok let me try.
Do you have any link or tool who gives me this type of structure if i pest my json response on it?
like json viewer

Comment: @Hardik1344 One on-line example is https://jsonlint.com but what I meant was that you might want to check the documentation for the API

Comment: Don't think this is completely correct `rate2` will decode even  when `int` inside `struDataString`

Comment: No it won't decode properly. Error is `"Parsed JSON number <3.5> does not fit in Int."`